# Every time i open an Activity, the Cursor moves to next record

Tags: android, database, android-activity, android-sqlite

My item is "title", items number is not fixed, it can increase since the user put more titles inside database through an edittext.

Now for test purpose i put 3 items/titles inside the database, here is the code i'm using inside my activityB onCreate(), as it is now every time I move from ActivityA to ActivityB the log prints my first item inside database..
I'd like it to always take the next item instead, and when at the end to take back the first one and go up again.

```
/** GET NEXT TITLE FROM DATABASE */
    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ActivityB.this);
    dbConnector.open();
    Cursor c = dbConnector.ListAllNotes();

    if (c != null && c.moveToNext()) {
        var = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"));

        Log.d("THIS:", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));

    }else if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        var = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"));

        Log.d("THIS:", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "NO DATA IN DATABASE YET", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    dbConnector.close();
```

on request this is DatabaseConnector.ListAllNotes()
at variables TITLE variable is declared as follow: `private static final String TITLE = "title";`

```
// List all data function
public Cursor ListAllNotes() {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { ID, TITLE }, null,
            null, null, null, TITLE);
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: what is not clear exactly? i can edit, my english is not perfect sorry.

Comment: Please show `DatabaseConnector.listAllNotes()`

Comment: You should keep a global counter (which will be your cursor index). So you can directly move the cursor to that record.

Comment: Yes I think i'll need a counter and store an increasing number inside shared pref perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are assuming that `query()` gives you the same `Cursor` object you got before but updates it to have rows for items that were inserted since the last time you queried. This is not the case.

Every call to `listAllNotes()` runs a *new* query on your database, and each query gives you a *new* Cursor. This new cursor has all the rows of the table and is always positioned before the first row. Then your code moves to the next position (i.e. the first row) and reads the title, which is always the first title in your database.

You need to either query the database *once* and hold onto that Cursor, or you need to remember which position you last looked at and use `Cursor.moveToPosition()` rather than `moveToNext()`.

Comment: Last thing you said yes, I'd need to remember somehow the row position every time i open activityB in order to go to the next one next time i'll open it.. e.g. i open actB and log gives me item1, i press home button i go back to actB again and log gives me item2, and so on, until reached max number of items present in the database, then i need to get back to first and start again